# TextInput cursor jump to right end when the input is empty

Tags: react-native

Cursor in the `TextInput` is jumping to the right end when the field is empty.

```
<TextInput 
    autoCorrect={ false }
    keyboardType="number-pad"
    autoCapitalize="none"
    placeholder="Inactivity time in seconds"
    onChangeText={ (value) => this.setState({ inactivityTime: value }) }
    value={ this.state.inactivityTime }
    style={ commons.pinInput } />
```

[image]

This issue only happens when the value `prop` of the `TextInput` is set to the `state`.

Answer (score 18):

After wasting lot of time i found the solution add
multiline={true}

Comment: Thanks dude. This works fine you can also use number of line. For example I wanted one line text so I used
numberOfLines={1}

Answer (score 3):

It seems that there is no place for the `placeholder` and the `cursor` at the same time when `textAlign: 'center'`.

To fix this, when the `TextInput` is `focused`, you should remove the placeholder also.

To do that i pass this to the `placeholder` prop.

```
placeholder={
    textInputRef.current?.isFocused() || inputValue !== ''
        ? undefined
        : placeholder
}
```

And then you would also need this `useRef`

```
  const textInputRef = useRef<TextInput | null>();
```

What this does, is to check if the `TextInput` if `focused`, or if the `inputValue` isn't empty/undefined then, we set the `placeholder` to `undefined` because, we want to remove the placeholder to leave space for the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

this is the exact problem i was facing, its a bug in React native textInput when the input is empty , the cursor jumps to the right . It was only happening when i used `textAlign` `center`.

So i had to go through the process of actually editing the design and assigning the placeholder and text to be centered in the left :

```
<TextInput
textAlign="left"
/>
```

Hope this fix helps. actually upvoting question too , so that. ican get a real fix for the answer.

Comment: That works. When I use `textAlign: "left"` there is no issue. But I can't change the design. Is there any other workaround to fix this without changing the alignment?

Comment: thats the problem i faced and its a bug, what you can do is use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-material-textfield , but thats a external library.

Comment: Any update on this? I don't want to use another library. And I can't change my design as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is not applicable to everyone, but if you can get away with not using a controlled component (i.e. don't pass a `value` prop to the `TextInput`) then this issue will not occur.

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace props "value" by "defaultvalue"

https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#defaultvalue

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, we will use a state hook

Declare a new variable like this:

```
const[value, setValue] = useState("");
```

create text input field like this:

```
<TextInput
          placeholder="Enter food item"
          style={{
            margin: 10,
            justifyContent: "center",
            flex: 1,
            textAlign: "center",
          }}
          onChangeText={(val) => setValue(val)}
        />
```

So this method will prevent you from getting cursor jumping to the right.

There is another props called caretHidden. You can use them too but it will make cursor disappear which won't be a good user experience.

```
caretHidden = {true}
```

If this works, don't forget to upvote me.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was failing only on Android. So what worked for me was:

```
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
   this.setState({value: ' '})
   setTimeout(() => {
       this.setState({value: undefined})
   }, 0.001);
}
```

Where 'value' is the same 'value' prop of the input. So you should execute that snippet in componentDidMount or useEffect. It's not fully tested, but I guess you can have a better idea now.

Answer (score 0):

here is what I found. Instead of applying alignSelf center to textInput I just added flexDirection row to parent View component and by doing justifyContent center the text becomes centered align.By using this approach the cursor also not goes to right end corner in android.

```
<View
    style={{
    width: '80%',
    height: 40,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    }}>
    <TextInput
     placeholder={'Enter amount      '}
     style={[styles.bottomText]}
    />
</View>
```